# Can anyone please help me with this problem of point set topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the set A ={(x,y,z)| $x^{2} + y^2 - z^2=1$} compact in $R^3$?

I think its not compact and the way to go about it is to prove that the set isnt bounded. I tried setting some upper bound (a,b,c) for the terms but I have no clue how to proceed from there.

I'm already failing my course in real analysis. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: $(n,1,n) \in A$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the equation as $z^2 = x^2 + y^2 -1$. Then it should be clear that however large $x$ and $y$ are you can find $z \in \mathbb{R}$, which implies it is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Restating the comment in geometric terms: the set $A$ contains the line where $y=1$ and $x=z$. Since this line isn’t bounded, neither is $A$.